# How to copy multiple records from a certain column from a table to another table in a column with vary option in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, insert, insert-update

How  to copy multiple records from a certain column from a table and insert to update another table in a column with vary option in mysql with a SQL command

Column: "targetCategory" condition all records contain Top/name_test2, Top/name_test2/%

column "title", "parentTopic refer data
Note: Data have root diferent not import exemple: Top/name_test752

```
        table_exemple1


       ===========================================================================
       |    aliasID    |    title     |    targetCategory     |    parentTopic    |
       ===========================================================================
No     |    1          | name_test752 | Top/name_test752/tel  | Top/name_test752  |
       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|-<----|    2          | name_test2   | Top/name_test2        | Top/name_test2    |
|      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
||-<---|    3          | 5            | Top/name_test2/etc/5  | Top/name_test2/etc|
||      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|||-<--|    4          | tesla        |  Top/name_test2/tesla | Top/name_test2    |
|||    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|||
|||
|||    **tabla_exemple2 before update**
|||    =====================================================================================================================================================================
|||    |    id         |    topic              |    topicShort         |    parentTopic        |    displayName    |    description    |    lastUpdate        | sitecount  |
|||    =====================================================================================================================================================================
|||    |    1          | Top/name_test/helloo  | helloo                | Top/name_test752      |     Nuul          |     hello         | 2010-06-19 04:10:14  |  324       |
|||    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|||    |    2          | Top/name_test2/nest   | nest                  | Top/name_test2/       |     Nuul          |      nest         | 2010-06-19 04:11:23  |  545435    |
|||    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|||    |    3          | Top/name_test2/etc/57 | 5                     | Top/name_test2/etc/   |     Nuul          |      5            |  2010-06-19 04:15:13 |  54354343  |
|||    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|||    |    4          | Top/name_test2/tesla1 | tesla                 |  Top/name_test2/      |     Nuul          |      tesla        |  2010-06-19 04:10:14 |  676756    |
|||    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|||  
|||
|||  **table_exemple2** after update
|||
|||
|||   =====================================================================================================================================================================
|||    |    id         |    topic              |    topicShort         |    parentTopic        |    displayName    |    description    |    lastUpdate        | sitecount  |
|||    =====================================================================================================================================================================
|||    |    1          | Top/name_test/helloo  | helloo                | Top/name_test752      |     Nuul          |     hello         | 2010-06-19 04:10:14  |  324       |
|||    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|||    |    2          | Top/name_test2/nest   | nest                  | Top/name_test2/       |     Nuul          |      nest         | 2010-06-19 04:11:23  |  545435    |
|||    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|||    |    3          | Top/name_test2/etc/57 | 5                     | Top/name_test2/etc/   |     Nuul          |      5            |  2010-06-19 04:15:13 |  54354343  |
|||    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|||    |    4          | Top/name_test2/tesla1 | tesla                 |  Top/name_test2/      |     Nuul          |      tesla        |  2010-06-19 04:10:14 |  676756    |
|||    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|||--->|    6          | Top/name_test2        | name_test2            | Top                   |     Nuul          |      name_test2   |  insert data         |  0         |
|      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|----->|    7          | Top/name_test2/etc/5  | 5                     | Top/name_test2/etc    |     Nuul          |      5            |  insert data         |  0         |
|      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|----->|    8          | Top/name_test2/tesla  | tesla                 | Top/name_test2        |     Nuul          |      tesla        |  insert data         |  0         |
       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       Data from "targetCategory" wil goo to "topic"
       data from "title" goo to "topicShort"
       Data from "parentTopic" goo to "parentTopic"
       I ned insert new data to column "displayName" well be "Nuul"
       I ned insert new data to column "description" well be idem "topicShort"
       I ned insert new data to column "displayName" well be "Nuul"
       I ned insert new data to column "lastUpdate" well be "data time inserition"
       I ned insert new data to column "displayName" well be "0"

       condition its column targetCategory data like Top/name_test2 and like Top/name_test2/%
```

Comment: How are you determining which records from `table_exemple1` that you wish to copy into `table_exemple2`?  How are you determining the values for the new record with `table_exemple2.id=6`, which seems to bear little resemblance to any of the original records from `table_exemple1`?

Comment: if root is diferent exemple Top/name_test50 is not necesary already there i dont want to create duplicates

Comment: Record `6` has `topic='Top/name_test2/32'` and `topicShort='32'`; according to your mapping, these values should have come from `targetCategory` and `title` respectively--but none of the records in `table_exemple1` have those values.

Comment: :) Yes it was my fault, so you understand now, ok sou you have solution?

Comment: Did you see the sqlfiddle link in [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996649/how-to-copy-multiple-records-from-a-certain-column-from-a-table-to-another-table#comment17712947_12996744) to my answer below?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but you can use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) together with appropriate [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html).  For example, to simply strip from `column2` everything up to the first colon:

```
INSERT INTO table_exemple3 (column4, column5, column6)
SELECT column1, SUBSTRING(column2, LOCATE(':', column2) + 1), column3
FROM   table_exemple2
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f01f4/1/0).

Comment: @OlariuRomeoVicentiu: Are you after something like [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3314e/1/0)?